# AWS ApiGateway: Unable to retrieve DistributionHostedZoneId attribute for AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

We are using AWS API Gateway, and I'm using CloudFormation to register a domain and an A record, as follows:

```
  Domain:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
    Properties:
    # EnvironmentName starts with an upper case letter, but the domain is created anyway
      DomainName: !Sub "${EnvironmentName}.mycompany.com"
      # this is a single certificate, used for all envs, and must be in virginia
      CertificateArn: !ImportValue DomainCertificateArn
      SecurityPolicy: TLS_1_2
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - EDGE
  ARecord:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: Fn::ImportValue  !Sub "${EnvironmentName}-HostedZoneId"
      # resolves to Z032215012YHJZINBEW
      Type: A
      Name: !Ref Domain
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: !GetAtt Domain.DistributionDomainName
        HostedZoneId: !GetAtt Domain.DistributionHostedZoneId
```

However, I'm seeing the following error when running this against my environment:

```
Unable to retrieve DistributionHostedZoneId attribute for AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
```

I've looked in the API Gateway console to check on this domain entry, and it does exist, with type EDGE, and all the other params present.  The Hosted zone id however is not the same value as that used in the template.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget-1.html#cfn-route53-aliastarget-hostedzoneid) you should be able to get this value from the `distributionHostedZoneId` attribute of your [AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-domainname.html) resource.

Based on the documentation and your file nothing appears to be configured incorrectly, there is also this line in the documentation regarding the `DistributionHostedZoneId`.

```
The only valid value is Z2FDTNDATAQYW2 for all regions.
```

This is the CloudFront distribution ID (as you're using regional) so you could set this value specifically. Otherwise validate that it gets created as a `EDGE` custom domain.